# Reformatting mixed content XML in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, reformat

I want to prevent IDEA to insert line breaks around certain elements, analogous to HTML formatting where certain elements (like `<b>`) are kept inline.

I have an XML dialect with a DTD that declares mixed content.

**DTD:**

```
<!ELEMENT mixed (#PCDATA|inline)*>
<!ELEMENT inline #PCDATA>
```

**XML file:**

```
<mixed>
  Some text with <inline>inline elements</inline>
  and a line break.
</mixed>
```

When I reformat the XML file, IDEA transforms it to

```
<mixed>
  Some text with 
  <inline>inline elements</inline>
  and a line break.
</mixed>
```

I have looked at all the options on Code style->XML->Other. The "Keep whitespace" option is too restrictive, as I want IDEA to break long lines.

Answer (score 6):

In IDEA 13 you could use new *Formatter Control* feature to disable autoformat of selected lines of code.
To enable this feature you should mark the following checkbox in the project settings:

[image: Formatter Control Settings]

Then insert selected markers in the comments to demarcate pieces of code that should not be formatted by *Reformat Code* tool, something like:

```
<root>
    <!-- @formatter:off -->
    <mixed>
        Some text with <inline>inline elements</inline>
        and a line break.
    </mixed>
    <!-- @formatter:on -->

    <mixed>
        Some text with
        <inline>inline elements</inline>
        and a line break.
    </mixed>
</root>
```

Unfortunately, there is no such feature in previous versions of IDEA and in that case the only known to me option is to format your code manually and not to use *Reformat Code* tool.

Comment: That is very interesting, and I did not know about it. However, what I would need is something like that to write into the DTD, so that the reformatted would leave selected elements like the "inline" element alone in general. I don't know if something like that exists, but IDEA can do it for inline elements in HTML and that seems to be defined quite generically with a relax-ng schema.

Answer (score 1):

After trying many things, I'm getting the impression that this will not be possible.
I've submitted a feature request:

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119650